# How can I plot something similar to this in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

[image: Graph plotting (x,y) coordinates and a string attached]

I have some (x,y) values with a string. For example data point named velocity has coordinates (1,1). I want to plot something almost identical to the picture attached. How to generate such a graph in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`matplotlib.pyplot.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'velocity': (1, 1), }  # data points

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(*zip(*data.values()))
ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=250)  # x axis limits
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=30)  # y axis limits
ax.set_xlabel('μ*')  # x axis label
ax.set_ylabel('β')  # y axis label

for name, coordinates in data.items():
    ax.annotate(name, coordinates)
```